# how make another transform animation after fade-in and existing transform?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a text which has fade-in and transform(translate) animation so after the fade-in and transform animation I want a moving text like up and down a lite, not too much in an infinite loop like you are waiting for loading of something

```css
.imgContaner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 86.6vh;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Sky-3.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgContaner p {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 #000000, 1px 0 #000000, 0 1px #000000, 0 -1px #000000;
  animation: 4s ease-in-out test ;
  opacity: 1;  

}

@keyframes test {
  from {   
    transform: translate(-50% , 400%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;  
}
}
```

```html
<div className={classes.imgContaner}>
      <p>Make Your Dreams Come True</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two ways with css.
First way: Add more frames in your @keyframes definition. Instead of using from and to properties, use percentages. For example:

```
@keyframes test {
  0% {   
    transform: translate(-50% , 400%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;  
  }
  75% {
    Do other stuff...
  }
  100% {
    Do other stuff...
  }
}
```

Second way: Chain animations to play after the other one. By adding delay to the second animation equal to the duration of first animation. Like:

```
animation: test 4s ease-in-out, otherAnim 2s ease-in-out 4s;
```

Note that you can't do it this way:

```
animation: test 4s ease-in-out;
animation: otherAnim 2s ease-in-out 4s;
```

This way first one will be overwriten by second one. Which is not what you want.

Comment: The second way worked perfectly by adding infinite to otherAnim wich you mentioned